# mozilla firefox addon-SDK button vanishes from navigation toolbar after a browser restart

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am creating an add-on for mozilla firefox using Add-on SDK. I have gone through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK regarding basics. However, I am now facing an issue with buttons. I want a button to be attached to the navigation toolbar. When I run the `main.js` file with "cfx run" the button shows up where it should until that firefox window is closed. If I create a `.xpi` file and open it in firefox it shows the button until we restart the browser. The bottom line is that **add-on button vanishes after browser restart**. Please, help me regarding this. Thanks in advance. The code is same as given in the mozilla developer tutorials.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be on-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: •the desired behavior, •a specific problem or error *and* •the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Are there any errors? Can you show us some code so we can get a better idea of what you're doing?

To debug this sorts of initialization problems try this:

1. start the browser
2. open the browser console, then hit 'clear' to remove existing log entries so you can easily see which ones are caused by the add-on
3. install the add-on - any errors?
4. open the add-on manager, disable the add-on, then enable it - any errors?
5. restart the browser with the add-on installed, then open the browser console. any errors?

Can you reproduce this issue with a simple example add-on, for example [this one](https://github.com/canuckistani/australis-ui)?